Matplotlib Runtime Error; latex could not be found
So, here are some fragments of my code that are pertinent to the problem. When I go to run this function, I get an error message that ends with RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found. I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.special
from scipy.special import logsumexp
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import numba as nb
import math
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import time as t

import os
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

def PlotPhaseEnergies():
    percentCut = 0.45
    
    plt.xlim(-35,25)
    phaseColors = ['red','orange','yellow','green']
    for bend in temps['BendingStrength'].unique():
        bendnum = float(bend)
        E,glog = histReweight(folder,bend)
       
        Estep=E[1]-E[0]
        S=glog[np.isfinite(glog)]
        
        
        Elim = E[np.isfinite(glog)]
        E_0 = []
        for entry in Elim:
            E_0.append(entry)
        E_0 = np.array(E_0)
        
        
        
        prevE_Phase = []
        for j in range(3):
            
            w = findWindowLength(S,j+3,Estep,0.8)
            Derivative = savgol_filter(S, window_length = w, polyorder=(j+3), deriv=(j+3), delta=Estep)
            Derivative = Derivative[:int(len(Derivative)*percentCut)]
            CheckList = np.multiply(Derivative[1:].copy(),Derivative[:-1].copy())
            ZeroCrossings = [num for num in CheckList if num < 0]
            ZeroCrossings = [v for i, v in enumerate(ZeroCrossings) if i % 2 == 0]
            indices = []
            for k in range(len(ZeroCrossings)):
                index = np.where(CheckList == ZeroCrossings[k])
            
                indices.append(int(index[0]))
            
            E_phase = E_0[indices] 
            rawE_phase = E_phase
            E_phase = E_phase[len(prevE_Phase):]
            
 

            if len(E_phase) > 0:
                for energy in E_phase:
                    plt.plot(energy, bendnum,marker = "o",markersize=10,markeredgecolor = phaseColors[j],markerfacecolor = phaseColors[j])
            prevE_Phase = rawE_phase
      
    plt.savefig("PhaseDiagram.png")

I have tried resetting the rcParams for plt, but that seems to have done nothing.

Well, do you have LaTeX installed?  You've told matplotlib to use this optional external program for better text rendering - but doing so does not magically cause LaTeX to appear on your computer, you have to install it yourself.

The error "RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found" arises because Matplotlib tries to use LaTeX for text rendering, but LaTeX is not installed or accessible on your system.
you can try ti disable LaTeX usage:
This is the simplest solution if you don't need LaTeX for text rendering in your plot.
You can disable it by setting plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False before plotting:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False  # Disable LaTeX

def PlotPhaseEnergies():
  # ... your plotting code here ...

# Call your plotting function
PlotPhaseEnergies()

